# Unable to build project with JOM

Tags: qt, visual-c++, cmake, qt-creator

I'm trying to build a project with MSVC 2013 and Qt Creator 4.4.0 with JOM and was having issues to configure JOM. So, I tried to erase Qt Creator's configuration files completely and start from scratch.

In the fresh Qt configuration, after I opened the project, I set the CMake (3.9.3) location and ran CMake on the project. Unfortunately, by default, the Qt 5.6.3 Kit seems to choose the NMake generator instead of the NMake JOM generator. After deleting the build directory, I changed the generator to NMake JOM in the Kit configurations, but met the following error message:

```
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "jom" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_276f9\fast"
```

Any idea of why this is happening? As far as I remember, Qt Creator is supposed to build the projects with JOM by default.

Comment: Does that command succeed when you type it at a command prompt in the same directory where CMake tried to run it?  Perhaps you don't have `jom` in your path.

Comment: But Qt Creator comes bundled with `jom.exe`. Shouldn't it figure out where it is itself?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: Well, no, `jom.exe` is not in my PATH, but I remember not having this problem before and I've never added it to the PATH. I'll try to put the QtCreator `bin` dir in the PATH (that's where `jom` is), but I'd like to know what changed and what's the point of having `jom` alongside Qt Creator if I have to manually include in the PATH.

Comment: So try putting it in your path and see if it works.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using ninja over jom. Jom is a cool thing, but rather a hack workflow wise, and given the support of ninja in CMake, it would be stupid not to use it.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact problem. Add the location of `jom.exe` (typically it is path like `[...]\Qt5.12.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\`) to your `PATH`.